# highcharts + sharepoint 2010 - renders blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, highcharts, sharepoint-2010

i'm having issues using highcharts in sharepoint 2010 with SPservices;  for some reason i cannot render a chart at all and am left with a completely blank page.  i am trying to scrub the code for errors but can't seem to find any apparent ones. i have tested with my own code and had the same blank page, and now have tried to use someone else's that they noted worked in their environment which yielded the same result. any insight would be much appreciated.  thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Phase'/></OrderBy></Query>",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields>",
    listName: "{5C783CEC-4E49-4DAD-B833-CD1F049C114D}",
    completefunc: processData
  });


function processData(xData, status) {
  var progData = [];

  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    progData.push({
      project: $(this).attr('ows_Title'),
      phase: $(this).attr('ows_Phase'),
      status: $(this).attr('ows_Status'),

    });
  });

  var chartData = [];
  var phaseData = _.groupBy(progData, 'phase');

  _.each(phaseData, function(row) {
    var phaseCount = row.length;

    chartData.push({
      name: row[0].phase,
      y: phaseCount
    });

  });

  renderChart(chartData);
});

function renderChart(data) {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'programchart',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: true
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Program by Phase'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000000',
          connectorColor: '#000000',
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' Times';
          }
        },
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Phase Count',
      data: data
    }]
  });
});



});

</script>
<div id="programchart"></div>
```

if it makes a difference, i am using jquery 1.8 and spservices 2014.

Comment: During your error checking, are you getting any notices in your web browser console?

Comment: nope :\.. the most i've gotten [and it's intermittent] is that the script took too long to load.  so i'm wondering if it's timing out before the actual script runs.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. How many points do you have in `chartData`?  Could you show en example of that array?

Comment: To add to what @PawełFus suggested, have you tried a smaller, sample set of data?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys -  @PawelFus, this is the code that some other person wrote & had success, so I literally just copied & pasted it filling in necessary info... there are 3 pts in chartData tho.

brightmatrix : i'm going to take your suggestion and create something much simpler & see if i get the same results.  i think the issue is with my CAMLQuery so will try there first.  ty!

Comment: hi all, thanks for your help again  - i went through my original code and the one above, and realized both work in chrome and mozilla but do not render in IE11.  not sure how to get around that; any advice would be helpful.  thanks!